# Windows DNS Names not resolving from an Apple Mac computer in java

Tags: java, networking, dns, hostname

Using the following code in Java 1.8, where host is a String equal to the ip address of a windows machine on the network

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
String hostName = addr.getHostName();
```

the DNS name for the machine resolves correctly when running the code from a windows host. However, running from two different Mac hosts, both of which resolve the name of the hosts in finder, return the ipaddress for the machine instead of the host name. I have looked extensively online and could not find any information regarding the problem. I'm assuming I am either doing something wrong, or their is a configuration problem stopping the DNS resolution, so hoping you guys know whats going on!

for an example

host = "192.168.1.100"
hostname return = "192.168.1.100" running the app from OSX but would return 'Computer-Name' on Windows

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MAC has a different meaning in networking; edited for clarity.

Comment: It might be of help if you show examples of what you mean, just to be 100% clear.